# Node size depending on degrees

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am trying to set the node size equal to nodes' degree.

My dataset is

```
    Person1            Age       Person2         Wedding
0   Adam John          3        Yao Ming         Green
1   Mary Abbey         5       Adam Lebron       Green
2   Samuel Bradley     24      Mary Abbey         Orange
3   Lucas Barney       12      Julie Lime        Yellow
4   Christopher Rice   0.9     Matt Red          Green
```

My code for building the network is

```
pos=nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.20, iterations=30)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size = degrees, nodelist=collist['value'], node_color=collist['Wedding'])
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width = [I['Age'] for i in dict(G.edges).values()])
```

I tried to define the degree as follows

```
degrees=[]
for x in df['Person1']: # all nodes size should depend on the degree, so also for Person2. Maybe this step is wrong 
    deg=G.degree[x]  
    degrees.append(deg)
```

but it seems to be not a scalar.

The error is

```
ValueError: s must be a scalar, or the same size as x and y
```

EDIT: I forgot to give an example of `collist['value']`:

```
Wedding variable    value
0   Green   Person1 Adam John
1   Green   Person1 Mary Abbey

... ... ... ...
75  Green   Person2 Yao Ming
76  Green   Person2 Adam Lebron
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that nodes in `G` have been obtained from columns `Person1` and `Person2`, the number of "persons" in `df['Person1']` is different from the total number of nodes in G, or at least in `nodelist=collist['value']`.

An easy fix would be to consider the degree of every node in `G`. Basically you were right, this step is wrong:

```
for x in df['Person1']:
```

you can change it to:

```
for x in G.nodes():
```

**or** use [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension):

```
degrees = [G.degree[node] for node in G.nodes()]
```

Or if you want only the nodes in `collist['value']`:

```
degrees = [G.degree[node] for node in collist['value']]
```

---

**Small Example:**

```
G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(100, 2, seed=42)


degrees = [G.degree[node] for node in G.nodes()]

pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size = degrees)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, alpha=0.1)
```

Result:
[image: Result from example above]

Comment: thanks for your help willcrack. However I am still getting the same error. I forgot to explain how the `collist['value']` looks like. Maybe this is causing the issue.

Comment: Instead of `G.nodes()` try `collist[‘value’]`

Comment: Thanks willcrack. It works now with no errors.

Comment: You can try multiplying the degree by some value: for example: `degrees=[1.2*G.degree[node] for node in collist['value']]'` will increase node size by 20%